# Content Repository type connection is missing in JDeveloper

Tags: jdeveloper, webcenter

I've recently started to learn about Oracle WebCenter.
I'm running Oracle UCM on VBox(downloaded from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/webcenter/downloads/owcs-portalfw-vbox-284132.html) and what I'm trying to do is create Content Repository Connection in the JDeveloper installed on my Host OS, but such option is simply missing from the menu. I mean there are few types of connections, but JDeveloper in VBox has more of them.

Creating Content Repository connection in the VBox works fine, but unfortunetly the whole OS in the VBox works very slowly.

Does anybody have any ideas how to fix this problem, so I could add Content Repository connection in the Windows OS?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the WebCenter extension for JDeveloper - use help->check for update in JDeveloper and check the Fusion Update center.
Or here:
http://www.oracle.com/ocom/groups/public/@otn/documents/webcontent/156082.xml